# Paper Lantern Theme Changed for Newly Transferred cPanel Account

Tags: accounts, cpanel, transfer

I just transferred a cPanel account in from another server. Paper Lantern is the default cPanel theme for all my accounts. However, the "Paper Lantern" theme for this one new account looks like an old X3 theme. If I switch to the X3 theme, it looks like the server's true X3 theme. However, if I switch back to Paper Lantern, it looks like the X3 theme from the old server.

What is causing the Paper Lantern theme to look like X3 for this one new account and how can I clear/reset it back to the actual Paper Lantern theme?

Note 1: This is only happening for the newly transferred account. Paper Lantern on all other accounts works fine.

Note 2: Paper Lantern on the old server was setup to look like X3, same as what is showing on the new server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the "Paper Lantern" theme for this one new account looks like an old X3 theme.

It sounds like you are seeing the "Retro" *style* of the "Paper Lantern" theme. (This does look very similar to the default ("root" *style*) X3 theme.)

If this is the case then you can easily switch back:
"Preferences" > "Change Style" and select "Basic".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the cause of this, I have had it happen as well.

If you run the following command at the prompt you will delete the current style for that account and it should reset to Paper Lantern if you have it as the current style.

```
# rm -Iv /home/**ACCOUNT**/var/cpanel/styled/current_style
```

If you would like to run it on all accounts

```
 # awk -F':' '/^[^#]/ { print $1; }' /etc/trueuserowners | xargs --no-run-if-empty -IACCOUNT sh -c '[ -L ~ACCOUNT/var/cpanel/styled/current_style ] && rm -Iv ~ACCOUNT/var/cpanel/styled/current_style'
```

Comment: I have no doubt this would have solved the issue. However, see the answer by @DocRoot above which is a much simpler resolution and explains why the issue happens.